# How to let serviceWorker control the page when the user firstly open the webpage?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

We team use serviceWorker to serve as a proxy layer between backend and frontend. The serviceWorker can help us fetch the request and we can detect the disabled CDN domain and respond the correct resources. I find a problem that when the serviceWorker is not installed on that browser, and the user firstly open our webpage on that brower, the serviceWorker install and activate after the webpage is render, resulting in the page like that:

[first in webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8K59w.png)

The CDN domain is disabled so the picture is not shown. The serviceWorker is installed after the  webpage renders, so it fails to fetch the request at the beginning of the render of page. Reloading the webpage, we can find serviceWorker works.

[after reload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZDU5.png)

I want to ask if there are some methods to allow the serviceWorker to begin to work before the webpage render?

Answer (score 0):

You should read [this](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#clientsclaim) if you haven't already. With that said - there are a couple different options that I can think of:

1. Display a loading animation or something indicating the image will eventually load. Then load the image once the service worker has activated and you've taken control of the client.
2. If possible - move your logic into a [cloudflare worker](https://workers.cloudflare.com/). It sounds like [this](https://github.com/cloudflare/worker-examples/tree/master/examples/third-party-scripts) would be a good example to start from for you.